# How to apply a block passed to each element of an array

Tags: ruby, arrays, dictionary, block, enumerable

I have an array of arrays, and I was wondering how I can call a block (if passed) to each of the elements of the array.

E.g.:

```
[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]].custom_method(first_par,second_par) {|element| p 'This is:' + element.inspect}
```

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation for the flatten function for Array class in Ruby:

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-flatten

Example :

```
a =[[1,2], [2,3], [3,4]]
b = a.flatten # gives [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4]
b.each { |myelement| 
   #do stuff 
}
```

Comment: Sorry about that. I have just edited my post that now give an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array#map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-map):

```
a =[[1,2], [2,3], [3,4]]
a.map { |x, y| puts "x: #{x}, y: #{y}" }

# x: 1, y: 2
# x: 2, y: 3
# x: 3, y: 4
```

You can also do fun stuff like:

```
a.map { |x,y| [x + y] }
# => [[3], [5], [7]]
```

or

```
b = a.map { |x,y| [x, x + y] }
# => [[1, 3], [2, 5], [3, 7]]
```